# No overload matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'/'System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventHandler'

Tags: c#

I am pretty new in the programming world and I have some questions. I would appreciate any help!!

I have a form "FW_Details" that is opened after a node from treeView2 (8 nodes) is selected, and the user clicked on a button. I want when the form opens to show the previously inserted data, let the user modify it and when it closes to save the data that was modified (for each particular node).

call the FW_Details form from the main form:

```
        foreach (TreeNode node in treeView2.Nodes)
        {
            if (node.IsSelected)
            {
                FW_Details fw = new FW_Details(node.Name);
                fw.Show(); 
            }
```

FW_Details contains this:

```
public partial class FW_Details : Form
{
    public  FW_Details(string name)
    {
        switch (name)
        {
            case "x":
                FW_Details_Load(null, null, "x");                
                break;
            case "y":
                FW_Details_Load(null, null, "y");
                break;
```

Event: FW_Details_Load

```
    private void FW_Details_Load(object sender, EventArgs e, string mycase)
    {
        switch (mycase)
        {
            case "x":
                Quellpfad.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.Quellpfad;
                Zielpfad.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.Zielpfad;
                Schlüsselwort.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.Schlüsselwort;
                DateiTyp.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.DateiTyp;
                Suchzeit.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.Suchzeit.ToString();
                break;
            case "y":
                Quellpfad.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.Quellpfad;
                Zielpfad.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.Zielpfad;
                Schlüsselwort.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.Schlüsselwort;
                DateiTyp.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.DateiTyp;
                Suchzeit.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.Suchzeit.ToString();
                break;
```

Event: FW_Details_FormClosed

```
    private void FW_Details_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e, string mycase)
    {

        switch (mycase)
        {
            case "x":
                Properties.Settings.Default.Quellpfad = Quellpfad.Text;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Zielpfad = Zielpfad.Text;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Schlüsselwort = Schlüsselwort.Text;
                Properties.Settings.Default.DateiTyp = DateiTyp.Text;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Suchzeit = Convert.ToInt32(Suchzeit.Text);
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                break;
```

Q1: I get 2 error messages:

`Error  1.  No overload for 'FW_Details_FormClosed' matches delegate 'System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventHandler'`

`Error  2   No overload for 'FW_Details_Load' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'`

Is it because I added for the event the paramaeter "string mycase"? How can I solve this problem?

Q2. After the FW_Details form loaded the data and appears on the screen..I want the user to be able to modify paramaeters in 
form and then save the parameters specified for each node...How can I do that? I should call the event FW_Details_FormClosed in the main form after show..but it is not recognized

Comment: You cannot add `string myCase` in your form closing event.Instead make a global variable and then access it

Answer (score 0):

You can't add parameters to the event handler delegates yourself. You have to comply to the delegates' signature that is defined by the event.

That means that `private void FW_Details_Load(object sender, EventArgs e, string mycase)` should become `private void FW_Details_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)`, etc.

You might want to make `mycase` a class variable, so you can access it inside the event handler:

```
public partial class FW_Details : Form
{
    private string mycase;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!! I don't really understand how would the event will be called for case x or y..

Comment: Sorry. I don't get your question.